# out of anger/ because of my anger

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, adverbial-phrases

a. I said that because of anger.

b. I said that because of my anger.

=========================

c. I said that out of anger.

d. I said that out of my anger.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?

I don't like (d), but it might be correct for all I know. I think (c) is the most natural way to express the idea. I think (a) and (b) are fine, but less natural than (c).

Comment: Here's an idea: When you have trouble identifying which of your phrases are natural, try Google Ngram. It will give you a good idea of their usage (most of the time). When that doesn't work, try putting your phrases in quotes and just google them, see the number of hits you get for each of them.

Comment: There's nothing grammatically incorrect about any of them; the question is, which is the most idiomatic? I would agree that it's (c).